# how do i trim empty text elements from a html string?

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing

What is the ***easiest*** way, ***without*** using regex, to trim empty text elements and line breaks from a html string ***using c#*** ?

When I say trim I mean from the start and end of the html

**example**

input:

```
<br /><br /><p></p><h1>Title</h1><p></p><br /><p>paragraph</p><p></p><p></p><br />
```

output:

```
<h1>Title</h1><p></p><br/><p>paragraph</p>
```

Comment: You can use this regular expression: `<[\w]*>\w+<\/[\w]*>`

Comment: Update: I think I misread your question.
How do you define an empty text element? Why is `<br/>` empty but `<p></p>` is not?

Comment: Why do you keep the empty `p`-tags in the middle? I'd use HtmlAgilityPack if i had to parse HTML.

Comment: thank you for your comments! i have edited the question to reflect the comments.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the p tag in the middle is to show that this element should not be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if you are looking for a tool or whatever, but I think a regular expression like this could work:

```
/<[^>]*><\\/[^>]*>/
```

Comment: should have been more precise. I wanted a way without using regex.